# where and how to deploy a Mean stack application contain front-end and back-end server(express + mongodb)?

Tags: node.js, web-deployment, mean-stack

I develop a single page Mean stack application, which runs on my local machine. But I lack website deploy experience, especially mean stack application deploy experience.So I want to ask :

1.I learnt that loopback support backend as a service api, as I also have front-end under the root dir, and back-end folder is under the root dir, but those two are in separate folder, those two are parallel.so the question is as the backend can be a service, where to hold the front end, to host it in a different server?

2.what is the efficient cloud platform to deploy, as I know, IBM bluemix and hereku, and amazon, did anyone used above service, and can recommend one?

Comment: As per my personal suggestion, For paid service go with amazon aws and if you are looking for learning purposes then go with openshift.

Comment: If you are new use Heroku with mlab for mongodb, deployment is piece of cake.

Comment: @JitendraKhatri  Thank you , I will try the could service you recommand

Comment: @Zeeshan Hassan Memon Thank you, heroku can only deploy the backend right?

Comment: Yes, When you say MEAN stack app it means node.js server (backend) which will be deployed to heroku and that node.js will be server your front-end files (angular.js). Hope that makes sense

Comment: @Zeeshan Hassan Memon, yes it is clear, so any could service to serve my front-end files? cheers

Comment: All can be done with heroku. Just see docs how to deploy node.js apps and you will understand how easy and fun it is.

Comment: @Zeeshan Hassan Memon, Thanks, I will have a try.